# Calculated Expected Number and Variance

Tags: probability

A fair die is tossed 300 times. Find the expected number and the variance of the
number of 2's.

Would the expected number be (1/6)^300 ?
And how do you find the variance?

HELP!

Comment: This is an $np$ problem ;). But more specifically do you know the mean and variance of a binomal distribution?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** for one toss, the distribution of the variable 'number of 2s' is Bernoulli with parameter $p=\frac 16$. Hence when the experimented is repeated, the distribution becomes
Binomial.

Comment: @calculus thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The probability that the number of $2$s will be $n$ is:

$$\binom{300}{n}\cdot\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^{n}\cdot\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{300-n}$$

Therefore, the expected number of $2$s is:

$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{300}n\cdot\binom{300}{n}\cdot\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^{n}\cdot\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{300-n}=50$$

Which is exactly what you could intuitively guess ($\frac{1}{6}$ of the total amount).

---

The variance of the number of $2$s is:

$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{300}(n-50)^2\cdot\binom{300}{n}\cdot\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^{n}\cdot\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{300-n}=41.666$$